# OpenGL - Changing window size with object

Tags: opengl

I'm new with OpenGL and I read codes from different sources. I don't understand what function provide the change of object size with window.

Code 1 -> http://codepad.org/1kSTAMOF

Code 2 -> http://codepad.org/Gs7CeBW2

math3d header for Code 2 ->http://codepad.org/Ptz3XBkp

Code 3 ->http://codepad.org/rFMWUktw

For example; the Code 1 and Code 2 create triangles and their sizes change with window size. However the Code 3 creates lines and their sizes doesn't change with changing window size. I don't understand which line of codes provide these properties and what must I do for provide same property for Code 3?(I couldn't share all links as link format because I'm not allowed)

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the code in the question. By all means have the links to back them up.

Comment: Do you mean math3d header file?

Comment: No. I mean the particular parts of the code you are having trouble with. If there's more than a couple of dozen lines then there's too much.

Comment: But that's my problem. I do not know which part of the code provide this property. I want to learn this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the width of the line doesnt change despite how much you zoom in or change the window size. Use glLineWidth(width) to make the line width vary with the size of the window

Answer (score 0):

Lines with a width of 1.0 are always rasterized one-pixel wide.  Using `glLineWidth` will change the width of all lines drawn to be the same size, regardless of the window size.

To get lines that scale with changes in window size (or more correctly, viewport size), you need to render them as filled primitives (i.e., GL_TRIANGLES, or GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP in OpenGL or OpenGL ES).  A solution to your problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514543/opengl-es-2-0-dynamically-change-line-width/14515510#14515510).  It's a little advanced, but hopefully it will make sense for you.