# OpenGL (ES 2.0) Dynamically Change Line Width

Tags: dynamic, opengl-es, width, line

I am currently drawing my model right now using a ton of `GL_LINES` all at a uniform radius.  I know that `glLineWidth` will change the radius of the *all* the lines but they each should have a different radius.  I am wondering if its possible using `glLineWidth` (in a different fashion) or another function?  How else should I go about it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Render them as a specially constructed triangle strip.  Specifically, render each line segment as a pair of triangles to form a quadraliterial, with the length of the quad matching the length of the line, and the width matching your "radius".  The real trick, however, is simulating GL_LINES, since line segments don't necessarily have to be connected to one another.  To do this in the triangle-strip case, you'll need to connect the pairs of triangles with a zero-area triangle, which won't be rendered (unless your OpenGL ES implementation isn't conformant).

For example, assuming we're in 2D (for simplicity; 3D's almost the same) say one of your line segment has endpoints (x1,y1) and (x2,y2), and a width of W, as shown below.
[image: line segment]
To replace this with a quad, we need to determine the coordinates of the corners, which requires a bit of math.  For a suitable 2D vector class, `vec2`

```
vec2  p1(x1, y1);
vec2  p2(x2, y2);
vec2  v = p2 - p1;

v /= v.length();  // make it a unit vector

vec2  vp(-v.y, v.x);  // compute the vector perpendicular to v

vec2  v[4];

v[0] = p1 + W/2 * vp;
v[1] = p1 - W/2 * vp;
v[2] = p2 + W/2 * vp;
v[3] = p2 - W/2 * vp;    

// Load the v[] array into a vertex-buffer object
```

That provides the solution taking a single line into a quad.  To connect them together, we need to create the triangle strip with *degenerate triangles* in it.  If we draw this as using `glDrawElements`, we can construct a simple index array to do this.  Say we converted two lines into quads as described above, giving us vertices v[0] ... v[7].  To make them into a single triangle strip, make an index list of

```
{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }
```

by repeating '3' in the list twice, we create a new triangle that connects the others together, yet doesn't show up.  If you repeat the last vertex of a quad, you can render your entire set of GL_LINES as a single triangle strip.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by a *degenerate triangle* and making adding a zth coordinate to this is not trivial.  Just adding a zth coordinate would give me a rectangular prism but how can I get that curvature a cylinder takes on?

Comment: A _degenerate triangle_ is one where two of the three vertices are identical.  As such, it has zero area, and won't be rasterized.  They are commonly used to render disconnected triangle strips in a single draw call.