# How to speed up rendering with OpenGL (ES) 2 Android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, rendering

I have developed a map using OpenGL-ES on android. It is displaying my map just fine, and I have just added touch event handling so I can move and fling it around, which is also working.

However it has a lag time of about 1 second. I would like the panning of the image obviously to be as smooth as possible.

I have quite a bit of vector data that I am displaying, but still, there must be alternatives to making the interactivity smoother, I have 17000 polygons (land parcels or lots) and about 1500 lines(road centre lines), they both get pre-loaded into lists  that hold FloatBuffers when the application launches. When I go to my map activity the renderer iterates through these lists, As you'll see in the code below.

I would really appreciate some pointers on how I can pick up speed.

(Just on another note, please ignore the scale detector and any rotation code, they are not working, all I am focusing on right now is panning the map.)

[image]

```
package com.ANDRRA1.utilities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;

public class CustomGLView extends GLSurfaceView {

    public vboCustomGLRenderer mGLRenderer;

    public CustomGLView(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomGLView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
        super(context, attrs);  
    }

    // Hides superclass method.
    public void setRenderer(vboCustomGLRenderer renderer) 
    {
        mGLRenderer = renderer;
        super.setRenderer(renderer);

        super.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    }

    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;

    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;
    private float mLastGestureX;
    private float mLastGestureY;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    private int mActivePointerId2 = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    float oL1X1, oL1Y1, oL1X2, oL1Y2;

    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleListener());
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new GestureListener());

    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

    //The following variable control the fling gesture
    private Interpolator animateInterpolator;
    private long startTime;
    private long endTime;
    private float totalAnimDx;
    private float totalAnimDy;
    private float lastAnimDx;
    private float lastAnimDy;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                    final float x = ev.getX();
                    final float y = ev.getY();

                    mLastTouchX = x;
                    mLastTouchY = y;
                    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
                }
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
                if (mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                    mActivePointerId2 = ev.getPointerId(1);

                    mLastGestureX = mScaleDetector.getFocusX();
                    mLastGestureY = mScaleDetector.getFocusY();

                    oL1X1 = ev.getX(ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId));
                    oL1Y1 = ev.getY(ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId));
                    oL1X2 = ev.getX(ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId2));
                    oL1Y2 = ev.getY(ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId2));
                }
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

                // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
                if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                    final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                    final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
                    final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

                    final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                    final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                    mPosX += dx;
                    mPosY += dy;

                    mGLRenderer.setEye(dx, dy);
                    requestRender();

                    mLastTouchX = x;
                    mLastTouchY = y;
                }
                else{
                    final float gx = mScaleDetector.getFocusX();
                    final float gy = mScaleDetector.getFocusY();

                    final float gdx = gx - mLastGestureX;
                    final float gdy = gy - mLastGestureY;

                    mPosX += gdx;
                    mPosY += gdy;

                    mLastGestureX = gx;
                    mLastGestureY = gy;
                }

                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {

                final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                        >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
                if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                    // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                    // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                    mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                }
                else{
                    final int tempPointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                    mLastTouchX = ev.getX(tempPointerIndex);
                    mLastTouchY = ev.getY(tempPointerIndex);
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10000.0f));

            //invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

    private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

            if (e1 == null || e2 == null){
                return false;
            }
            final float distanceTimeFactor = 0.4f;
            final float totalDx = (distanceTimeFactor * velocityX/2);
            final float totalDy = (distanceTimeFactor * velocityY/2);

            onAnimateMove(totalDx, totalDy, (long) (1000 * distanceTimeFactor));
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void onAnimateMove(float dx, float dy, long duration) {
        animateInterpolator = new DecelerateInterpolator();
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        endTime = startTime + duration;
        totalAnimDx = dx;
        totalAnimDy = dy;
        lastAnimDx = 0;
        lastAnimDy = 0;

        post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                onAnimateStep();
            }
        });
    }

    private void onAnimateStep() {
        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        float percentTime = (float) (curTime - startTime) / (float) (endTime - startTime);
        float percentDistance = animateInterpolator.getInterpolation(percentTime);
        float curDx = percentDistance * totalAnimDx;
        float curDy = percentDistance * totalAnimDy;

        float diffCurDx = curDx - lastAnimDx;
        float diffCurDy = curDy - lastAnimDy;
        lastAnimDx = curDx;
        lastAnimDy = curDy;

        doAnimation(diffCurDx, diffCurDy);

        if (percentTime < 1.0f) {
            post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    onAnimateStep();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void doAnimation(float diffDx, float diffDy) {
        mPosX += diffDx;
        mPosY += diffDy;

        mGLRenderer.setEye(diffDx, diffDy);
        requestRender();
    }

    public float angleBetween2Lines(float L1X1, float L1Y1, float L1X2, float L1Y2, float L2X1, float L2Y1, float L2X2, float L2Y2)
    {
        float angle1 = (float) Math.atan2(L1Y1 - L1Y2, L1X1 - L1X2);
        float angle2 = (float) Math.atan2(L2Y1 - L2Y2, L2X1 - L2X2);

        float angleDelta = findAngleDelta( (float)Math.toDegrees(angle1), (float)Math.toDegrees(angle2));
        return -angleDelta;
    }

    private float findAngleDelta( float angle1, float angle2 )
    {
        return angle1 - angle2;
    }
}
```

.

```
package com.ANDRRA1.utilities;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.util.ListIterator;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.Matrix;

public class vboCustomGLRenderer  implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    /**
     * Store the model matrix. This matrix is used to move models from object space (where each model can be thought
     * of being located at the center of the universe) to world space.
     */
    private float[] mModelMatrix = new float[16];

    /**
     * Store the view matrix. This can be thought of as our camera. This matrix transforms world space to eye space;
     * it positions things relative to our eye.
     */
    private float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];

    /** Store the projection matrix. This is used to project the scene onto a 2D viewport. */
    private float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];

    /** Allocate storage for the final combined matrix. This will be passed into the shader program. */
    private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];

    /** This will be used to pass in the transformation matrix. */
    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

    /** This will be used to pass in model position information. */
    private int mPositionHandle;

    /** This will be used to pass in model color information. */
    private int mColorUniformLocation;

    /** How many bytes per float. */
    private final int mBytesPerFloat = 4;   

    /** Offset of the position data. */
    private final int mPositionOffset = 0;

    /** Size of the position data in elements. */
    private final int mPositionDataSize = 3;

    /** How many elements per vertex for double values. */
    private final int mPositionFloatStrideBytes = mPositionDataSize * mBytesPerFloat;

    // geometry types
    private final byte wkbPoint = 1;
    private final byte wkbLineString = 2;
    private final byte wkbPolygon = 3;
    //private final byte wkbMultiPoint = 4;
    //private final byte wkbMultiLineString = 5;
    //private final byte wkbMultiPolygon = 6;
    //private final byte wkbGeometryCollection = 7;

    // Big Endian
    final int wkbXDR = 0;
    // Little Endian
    final int wkbNDR = 1;


    float count = 0;

    // Position the eye behind the origin.
    public volatile float eyeX = default_settings.mbrMinX + ((default_settings.mbrMaxX - default_settings.mbrMinX)/2);
    public volatile float eyeY = default_settings.mbrMinY + ((default_settings.mbrMaxY - default_settings.mbrMinY)/2);

    // Position the eye behind the origin.
    //final float eyeZ = 1.5f;
    public volatile float eyeZ = 1.5f;

    // We are looking toward the distance
    public volatile float lookX = eyeX;
    public volatile float lookY = eyeY;
    public volatile float lookZ = 0.0f;

    // Set our up vector. This is where our head would be pointing were we holding the camera.
    public volatile float upX = 0.0f;
    public volatile float upY = 1.0f;
    public volatile float upZ = 0.0f;


    public vboCustomGLRenderer() {
    }

    public void setEye(float x, float y){

        eyeX -= (x/screen_vs_map_horz_ratio);
        lookX = eyeX;
        eyeY += (y/screen_vs_map_vert_ratio);
        lookY = eyeY;

        // Set the camera position (View matrix)
        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {


        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);

        // Set the background frame color
        //White
        GLES20.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        // Set the view matrix. This matrix can be said to represent the camera position.
        // NOTE: In OpenGL 1, a ModelView matrix is used, which is a combination of a model and
        // view matrix. In OpenGL 2, we can keep track of these matrices separately if we choose.
        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);

        final String vertexShader =
            "uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;      \n"     // A constant representing the combined model/view/projection matrix.

          + "attribute vec4 a_Position;     \n"     // Per-vertex position information we will pass in.
          + "attribute vec4 a_Color;        \n"     // Per-vertex color information we will pass in.              

          + "varying vec4 v_Color;          \n"     // This will be passed into the fragment shader.

          + "void main()                    \n"     // The entry point for our vertex shader.
          + "{                              \n"
          + "   v_Color = a_Color;          \n"     // Pass the color through to the fragment shader. 
                                                    // It will be interpolated across the triangle.
          + "   gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix   \n"     // gl_Position is a special variable used to store the final position.
          + "               * a_Position;   \n"     // Multiply the vertex by the matrix to get the final point in                                                                   
          + "}                              \n";    // normalized screen coordinates.

        final String fragmentShader =
                "precision mediump float;       \n"     // Set the default precision to medium. We don't need as high of a 
                                                        // precision in the fragment shader.                
              + "uniform vec4 u_Color;          \n"     // This is the color from the vertex shader interpolated across the 
                                                        // triangle per fragment.             
              + "void main()                    \n"     // The entry point for our fragment shader.
              + "{                              \n"
              + "   gl_FragColor = u_Color;     \n"     // Pass the color directly through the pipeline.          
              + "}                              \n";                                                

        // Load in the vertex shader.
        int vertexShaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

        if (vertexShaderHandle != 0) 
        {
            // Pass in the shader source.
            GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShaderHandle, vertexShader);

            // Compile the shader.
            GLES20.glCompileShader(vertexShaderHandle);

            // Get the compilation status.
            final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetShaderiv(vertexShaderHandle, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);

            // If the compilation failed, delete the shader.
            if (compileStatus[0] == 0) 
            {               
                GLES20.glDeleteShader(vertexShaderHandle);
                vertexShaderHandle = 0;
            }
        }

        if (vertexShaderHandle == 0)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating vertex shader.");
        }

        // Load in the fragment shader shader.
        int fragmentShaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        if (fragmentShaderHandle != 0) 
        {
            // Pass in the shader source.
            GLES20.glShaderSource(fragmentShaderHandle, fragmentShader);

            // Compile the shader.
            GLES20.glCompileShader(fragmentShaderHandle);

            // Get the compilation status.
            final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetShaderiv(fragmentShaderHandle, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);

            // If the compilation failed, delete the shader.
            if (compileStatus[0] == 0) 
            {               
                GLES20.glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderHandle);
                fragmentShaderHandle = 0;
            }
        }

        if (fragmentShaderHandle == 0)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating fragment shader.");
        }

        // Create a program object and store the handle to it.
        int programHandle = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

        if (programHandle != 0) 
        {
            // Bind the vertex shader to the program.
            GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, vertexShaderHandle);           

            // Bind the fragment shader to the program.
            GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, fragmentShaderHandle);

            // Bind attributes
            GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, 0, "a_Position");
            GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, 1, "a_Color");

            // Link the two shaders together into a program.
            GLES20.glLinkProgram(programHandle);

            // Get the link status.
            final int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetProgramiv(programHandle, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);

            // If the link failed, delete the program.
            if (linkStatus[0] == 0) 
            {               
                GLES20.glDeleteProgram(programHandle);
                programHandle = 0;
            }
        }

        if (programHandle == 0)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating program.");
        }

        // Set program handles. These will later be used to pass in values to the program.
        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "u_MVPMatrix");
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "a_Position");
        mColorUniformLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "u_Color");

        // Tell OpenGL to use this program when rendering.
        GLES20.glUseProgram(programHandle);

    }

    static float mWidth = 0;
    static float mHeight = 0;
    static float mLeft = 0;
    static float mRight = 0;
    static float mTop = 0;
    static float mBottom = 0;
    static float mRatio = 0;
    float screen_width_height_ratio;
    float screen_height_width_ratio;
    final float near = 1.5f;
    final float far = 10.0f;

    double screen_vs_map_horz_ratio = 0;
    double screen_vs_map_vert_ratio = 0;

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {

        // Adjust the viewport based on geometry changes,
        // such as screen rotation
        // Set the OpenGL viewport to the same size as the surface.
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        //Log.d("","onSurfaceChanged");

        screen_width_height_ratio = (float) width / height;
        screen_height_width_ratio = (float) height / width;

        //Initialize
        if (mRatio == 0){
            mWidth = (float) width;
            mHeight = (float) height;

            //map height to width ratio
            float map_extents_width = default_settings.mbrMaxX - default_settings.mbrMinX;
            float map_extents_height = default_settings.mbrMaxY - default_settings.mbrMinY;
            float map_width_height_ratio = map_extents_width/map_extents_height;
            //float map_height_width_ratio = map_extents_height/map_extents_width;
            if (screen_width_height_ratio > map_width_height_ratio){
                mRight = (screen_width_height_ratio * map_extents_height)/2;
                mLeft = -mRight;
                mTop = map_extents_height/2;
                mBottom = -mTop;
            }
            else{
                mRight = map_extents_width/2;
                mLeft = -mRight;
                mTop = (screen_height_width_ratio * map_extents_width)/2;
                mBottom = -mTop;
            }

            mRatio = screen_width_height_ratio;
        }

        if (screen_width_height_ratio != mRatio){
            final float wRatio = width/mWidth;
            final float oldWidth = mRight - mLeft;
            final float newWidth = wRatio * oldWidth;
            final float widthDiff = (newWidth - oldWidth)/2;
            mLeft = mLeft - widthDiff;
            mRight = mRight + widthDiff;

            final float hRatio = height/mHeight;
            final float oldHeight = mTop - mBottom;
            final float newHeight = hRatio * oldHeight;
            final float heightDiff = (newHeight - oldHeight)/2;
            mBottom = mBottom - heightDiff;
            mTop = mTop + heightDiff;

            mWidth = (float) width;
            mHeight = (float) height;

            mRatio = screen_width_height_ratio;
        }

        screen_vs_map_horz_ratio = (mWidth/(mRight-mLeft));
        screen_vs_map_vert_ratio = (mHeight/(mTop-mBottom));

        Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, mLeft, mRight, mBottom, mTop, near, far);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //The following lists hold the vector data in FloatBuffers pre-loaded from when then application starts
        ListIterator<mapLayer> orgNonAssetCatLayersList_it = default_settings.orgNonAssetCatMappableLayers.listIterator();
        while (orgNonAssetCatLayersList_it.hasNext()) {
            mapLayer MapLayer = orgNonAssetCatLayersList_it.next();

            ListIterator<FloatBuffer> mapLayerObjectList_it = MapLayer.objFloatBuffer.listIterator();
            ListIterator<Byte> mapLayerObjectTypeList_it = MapLayer.objTypeArray.listIterator();
            while (mapLayerObjectTypeList_it.hasNext()) {

                switch (mapLayerObjectTypeList_it.next()) {
                    case wkbPoint:
                        break;
                    case wkbLineString:
                        Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
                        //Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
                        drawLineString(mapLayerObjectList_it.next(), MapLayer.lineStringObjColor);
                        break;
                    case wkbPolygon:
                        Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
                        //Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
                        drawPolygon(mapLayerObjectList_it.next(), MapLayer.polygonObjColor);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawLineString(final FloatBuffer geometryBuffer, final float[] colorArray)
    {
        // Pass in the position information
        geometryBuffer.position(mPositionOffset);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, mPositionDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, mPositionFloatStrideBytes, geometryBuffer);

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        GLES20.glUniform4f(mColorUniformLocation, colorArray[0], colorArray[1], colorArray[2], 1f);

        // This multiplies the view matrix by the model matrix, and stores the result in the MVP matrix
        // (which currently contains model * view).
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);

        // This multiplies the modelview matrix by the projection matrix, and stores the result in the MVP matrix
        // (which now contains model * view * projection).
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);

        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);

        GLES20.glLineWidth(2.0f);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, geometryBuffer.capacity()/mPositionDataSize);
    }

    private void drawPolygon(final FloatBuffer geometryBuffer, final float[] colorArray)
    {
        // Pass in the position information
        geometryBuffer.position(mPositionOffset);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, mPositionDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, mPositionFloatStrideBytes, geometryBuffer);

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        GLES20.glUniform4f(mColorUniformLocation, colorArray[0], colorArray[1], colorArray[2], 1f);

        // This multiplies the view matrix by the model matrix, and stores the result in the MVP matrix
        // (which currently contains model * view).
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);

        // This multiplies the modelview matrix by the projection matrix, and stores the result in the MVP matrix
        // (which now contains model * view * projection).
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);

        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);

        GLES20.glLineWidth(1.0f);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, geometryBuffer.capacity()/mPositionDataSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Hank. Have read you question and looked at you image attachment and was very interested. Im forcing right now with the rendering small office map problem with two floors. It seems to me that you attachment it exactly what I need, cause as I understand you map is zoomable and rotatable. Im just looking for a place to start - any sites, books, technologies about map rendering. If you have information, of code snippets and can point me into rithg direction I will be very appresiate. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other answers here are already very good and show places to look and things to be improved. I suspect the slowdown is from calling drawPolygon and drawLine thousands of times per draw frame (if you have thousands of polygons and lines), and each one calling OpenGL methods many times per method call. You really want to batch these calls so that you draw all the polygons and all the lines in single separate draw calls.

It’s hard to time stuff accurately, OpenGL buffers the calls and even the Android tracer gives inaccurate results, from my experience. What you can do is try removing and changing the code  between runs, time the entire draw loop and see how things change then.

Try removing Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);, and re-engineer the app to put your data into a vertex buffer object, bound with GL_STATIC_DRAW. Draw all of the lines with a single draw call. To avoid state changes and breaking up draw calls, you can put the color in as an attribute instead of as a uniform. You can also calculate and pass in the matrix uniform once per overall draw instead of per line.

Comment: And if you don't want to change the VBOs after creating them, GL_STATIC_DRAW works, too.

Comment: I have put all my FloatBuffers into two large single FloatBuffers. I am now wondering how I go about adjusting my drawPolygon function to suit the batch? Also where the best place to set GLES20.glBufferData(target, size, data, usage) is?

Comment: I should have gone into more detail, the polygons and lines are drawing but they are now one continuous polygon and one continuous line. It is a bit of a mess to look at. However at this point it is now very fast and panning the map is smooth. Whether this changes by breaking up them up remains to be seen. Do I need to send GLES an array of start positions or something along those lines for each individual buffer within the large buffer?

Comment: If you just want to set the data once you can call glBufferData from onSurfaceCreated.

Can you find a way to generate the line data so that you can draw the lines individually instead of as line loops/strips? That would let you batch all the lines as well. This may increase the size of your data, but saving on thousands of draw calls may be worth it.  If you use index buffers, the increase in size will be limited to the indices which can take up a lot less space than the vertices.

Comment: To continue to use different colors, you can add the color as an attribute of the vertex data instead of as a uniform. You can also just pass in the uniform matrix once, before you start drawing. No need to calculate it per individual line/polygon unless you want to move them around relative to each other.

Comment: Yes I believe I can generate the lines that way, I'll read up on lesson eight(http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-eight-an-introduction-to-index-buffer-objects-ibos/) before I start :)

Comment: Just thinking if I have this 17000 polygons some of them have 4 sides a lot of them have more. So if we say at a minimum 17000*4 = 68000 points.
If I create an index buffer and these can be a byte or short value, then won't I hit issues with values over (32,767 * 2)?

Comment: Yeap if I create a ShortBuffer and try to stick my indexing for each point I get some pretty interesting results. For the polygons there were a total of 250625 points, averaging about 15 points per polygon. Obviously this won't go into a java short which can only go to 32767 even if it were able to handle unsigned it would only go to 65535. What do you think could resolve this?

Comment: You can go up to 65535 by casting the short as follows: (short) 65535; It will “just work” even if Java thinks it’s -32768.

What if you just use a single vertex buffer for now without using an index buffer? That will reduce the complexity of the code. Later on you can figure out a way to LOD the data to get to or under 65536 unique vertices, or you can render using multiple index/vertex buffers.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you focus on limiting the amount you're drawing based on zoom level and viewport rather than try to optimize rendering efficiency.  Chances are, you're not making too many inefficient rendering calls if you're up to 17,000 polygons with decent response time.

Look at the picture you posted.  If you're rendering 17,000 polygons and 1,500 lines there, most the detail wasted since we can't see that level of detail right?  I certainly don't see 17,000 polygons.

Instead, keep the full details loaded, and write code to limit detail based on zoom level.  This approach is unsurprisingly called a [level of detail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_detail) algorithm. If you've ever done much with MipMaps its based on the same principal.

I would calculate level of detail data for all zoom levels you desire, and reference this cached data based on current zoom level.  When the user isn't at one of your discrete zoom levels, just reference the closest one and scale.

When high detail is needed at closer zoom levels, you can keep things fast by [culling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_surface_determination#Culling_and_VSD) what lines and polygons don't need to be rendered in your level of detail data using [Spatial Partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning) algorithms.

If you need clarification on any points let me know.  This stuff is easy to talk about but tricky to code.  Good luck!

EDIT:

One LoD implementation would be to calculate your polygon and line positions based on your matrix scaling.  Then, discard any points which aren't sufficiently far apart.  I'd just cast their floating point positions to ints for a start, and see what it looks like.  Do this for several scaling levels.  Store these results in an array, then round whatever scaling level you're at to select the nearest cached LoD data.

Comment: Lol I can't believe you didn't count them. I agree a lot of the detail is wasted. Level of detail(LOD) seems the best place to start, I will look at culling once I'm ready to zoom in. I haven't done anything with Mipmaps by the way. Finding an algorithm that suits seems the next step, any ideas where to find existing ones? I suppose giving each Float buffer a kind of zoom index and sorting it on that index, might be a way to go, however finding which takes priority over another, how does that work?

Comment: I tried searching for existing LoD algorithms for lines and came up with little.  I've edited my question to include a possible solution.  It should be easy to implement.

Answer (score 2):

A few things leap out a me.

1) Don't create object in your drawing routines such as onDrawFrame. Iterators such as

```
    ListIterator<mapLayer> orgNonAssetCatLayersList_it = default_settings.orgNonAssetCatMappableLayers.listIterator();
```

create objects and creating objects in your drawing routine hurts performance.

2) Minimize OpenGL calls a much as possible. Java still needs to cross the JNI boundary when you do OpenGL calls so if you can put everything in a few large bytebuffers and avoid changing OpenGL state. I would have tried to organize the data into as few a possible buffers that draws the lines and another set the draw the polygons.

You may want to consider only rendering parts of the data at various zoom levels. Others may have better ideas and if you look around SO or online I'm sure you'll find them.

3) And always measure your performance to see where your real problems are. Android has a variety of tools ([Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) [Systrace](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html), [OpenGL ES Tracer](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/gltracer.html)) available.

See for more general Android performance tips: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html

Comment: Placing a set of polygons into one buffer sounds interesting how would it know when it has finished one polygon and started another?

Comment: I didn't realize you were using LINE_LOOP/LINE_STRIP and was thinking of using degenerate triangles with TRIANGLE_STRIP to draw multiple lines. See this SO question on line width: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514543/opengl-es-2-0-dynamically-change-line-width

Answer (score 2):

No one is mentioning FBO's?? I mean, LOD would be a good approach, but in some cases you can use FBOs. It would depend on many things, but you should consider them!

You can render your hole scene (or part of it) to a frame buffer object and show the image instead of drawing the scene each frame. That reduces the polygon count to just a few (2 for the best case, which is one square).

A new problem would be how to handle the panning/zooming as you'd need to recompute the fbo's dynamically. You can just draw a blury image until the fbo is ready or you can take more advanced approaches with some pre-loading, like dividing the map in squares and preload 9 of them (center and 8 neighbors) as google-maps does to load its maps data.

You'll also need to take a look at memory consumption, you can't just draw every combination to FBO's.

I repeat, FBOs are not a "stand-alone" solution, just keep them mind to see if you can use them somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this in a VM or on a real handset?

Can you add some code to check the rendertime of your functions?

Try to find out what is taking time that way.

Comment: Handset, its approx 1000ms per full render

Comment: Yes but how much is it per step. How long does
onDrawFrame, drawPolygon and drawLineString take each?